# An InnoDB column marked with "using btree" why?

Tags: mysql

from an unknown reason:

```
CREATE TABLE  `orders_products` (
  `ORDER_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `QUANTITY` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `USER_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ORDER_ID`,`PRODUCT_ID`,`USER_ID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `FK_orders_products_3` (`USER_ID`),
  KEY `FK_orders_products_2` (`PRODUCT_ID`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_products_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ORDER_ID`) REFERENCES `orders` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_products_2` FOREIGN KEY (`PRODUCT_ID`) REFERENCES `products` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_orders_products_3` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

primary key and FK_orders_products_2 got BTREE. How to know it? Neither SHOW INDEX, nor DESCRIBE TABLE describes who using BTREE and who doesnt

Comment: All InnoDB indexes are btrees, so specifically marking them so is a little strange. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-physical-structure.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get information about the keys using

```
 SHOW KEYS FROM orders_products
```

There's an INDEX_TYPE column in that resultset.

Comment: interestingly, it shows "btree" for all columns... while not all columns are btree here